# How to create an array in for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm coming from Python so trying to figure out basic things in Js.

I have the following:

```
{
  name: 'Jobs ',
  path: '/plat/jobs',
  meta: {
    label: 'jobs',
    link: 'jobs/Basic.vue'
  },
```

what I want is to create this block for each element in a list using a for loop (including the brackets)

in python this would be something like

```
for i in items:
    {
      name: i.name,
      path: i.path,
      meta: {
        label: i.label,
        link: i.link
     }
```

How do I do this in js?  what even is the object type here?  Is it just a javascript dictionary?

```
  children: [
    let new_items = items.map(i => ({
      name: i.name,
      path: i.path,
      meta: {
        label: i.label,
        link: i.link
      }
    }));

    console.log(new_items);
      component: lazyLoading('android/Basic')
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't think this will work because i need each dictionary listed under children.

Comment: You may want to define your list (e.g., `items`), describe your input and your expected output.  You call it a *list*, is it an *array*?

Comment: it's called javascript object notation. Otherwise known as JSON.

Comment: You’ll need to give an example of what your data structure is and then how you expect it.

Comment: You can assign `children` to a function, but it seems like you may want to run the code outside of the object.  Again, you'll have to give more information on your data structure and what you want.  This is incomplete

Answer (score 3):

Included is an example that operates on an array of objects, returning a new array of objects.  An object is overloaded in JavaScript, but in this case it is synonymous in other languages to a hash, object, or dictionary (depending on application).

```js
let items = [{
  name: 'foo',
  path: 'foopath',
  label: 'foolabel',
  link: 'foolink'
}, {
  name: 'bar',
  path: 'barpath',
  label: 'barlabel',
  link: 'barlink'
}];

let new_items = items.map(i => ({
  name: i.name,
  path: i.path,
  meta: {
    label: i.label,
    link: i.link
  }
}));

console.log(new_items);
```

That said, a new array is not necessary since it's possible to edit the object directly:

```js
let items = [{
  name: 'foo',
  path: 'foopath',
  label: 'foolabel',
  link: 'foolink'
}, {
  name: 'bar',
  path: 'barpath',
  label: 'barlabel',
  link: 'barlink'
}];

items.forEach(i => {
  i.meta = {label:i.label, link:i.link};
  delete i.label;
  delete i.link;
});

console.log(items);
```

Comment: in my updated example i think i am trying to append each dictionary to the children list ?

Comment: each object needs to be under children

Answer (score 1):

I would use the list.map function

```
items.map(i => {
    return {
        name: i.name,
        path: i.path,
        meta: {
            label: i.label,
            link: i.link
        }
     }))
```

This will return a new list of items as specified

NOTE: this can be simplified further with an implicit return

```
items.map(i => ({
    name: i.name,
    path: i.path,
    meta: {
        label: i.label,
        link: i.link
    }
}))
```